# Replace string in text file from batch cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Assume that I have a text file with following content:

```
config {
  host: <host_value>,
  port: <port_value>
}
```

I need get user input from cmd and fill to above file 
(Ex: when user input '10.0.0.1' and '27017' ,I need update file content to :

```
config {
  host: '10.0.0.1',
  port: '27017'
}
```

by using Windows command-line

I googling for this but still have no expectation

Comment: Is that the entire file or is there more to it? If the file is truly that small, it may be worth simply recreating the file with the script - it will certainly be easier; find-and-replace in batch is extremely complicated.

Comment: How are the users inputting their values exactly?

Comment: Based on the "I need to get" part, I'm assuming this is a "write my code for me" question. It's a shame, really, since there's only one way to get user input as a string in batch, and only one way to output strings to a file.

Comment: Sorry , I know how to get user input from command line , but I dont know how to set these input to a specifice position in text file , In fact ,my file contains more text longer than in my example

Comment: Read `FOR /F` [Loop command: against a set of files](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). Then you could start with something similar to `for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims='" %G in ("D:\files\29226411.txt") do @echo [%G] [%H] [%I]` (or with `delims=<`) to see how it works... Fell free to return here via [edit] your question and paste achieved code if you could  freeze on anything.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did you Google? I just searched SO for [[batch-file] replace string in file](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+replace+string+in+file) and found 28 pages of results.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have to have it named `<host_value>` but maybe `host_value` you could use this script:

```
set input=input.txt
set output=output.txt
if exist "%output%" del /f /q "%output%"
set /p search="host_value"
set /p replace="10.0.0.1"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%input%) do (
  set newline=%%a
  call set newline=%%newline:%search%=%replace%%%
  call echo %%output%% >>%output%
)
```

This would create a new file wich you could rename after the process using

```
del /f /q %input%
ren %output% %input%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) for it:

```
set /p host=Input for Host: 

set /p port=Input for Port: 

vim -c "%s/<host_value>/%host%/g|%s/<port_value>/%port%/g" config_file.txt
```